# Can I install the Android M Developer Preview on HTC One?

Tags: rom, 6.0-marshmallow, developer-preview

So I just wanted to try out the new Android M developer preview on my HTC One M8, but the only build available is for Nexus devices.

If I flashed it on my HTC with MultiRom, and it bricked, could I easily just remove it with MultiRom? Or would it mess up my main stock 5.0 ROM also?

In that case, should I make a Nandroid backup with TWRP?

Comment: Thanks guys, it simply failed to flash, nothing was lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The M Preview images are for nexuses only so it wont work on any other device, although if you really wanted to try out Android M there is a possibility that a developer somewhere takes interest in developing one for your phone as soon as source code is released but you will have to wait though. You should be able to remove the ROM from MultiROM but its always advisable to take a backup when changing ROMs.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing when you want to try out dev builds is to find the forum for your phone on XDA and see if some one ported/built a version for your phone. Just do a quick google search for XDA phoneinfohere Android M

Answer (score -1):

It would mess up your phone way too badly lol! Better stick with the ROM you're using and wait for the devs to bring up the M preview for your device.